# Firefox is not accepting my mouse interaction

Tags: macos, firefox, mouse, config

Firefox is not allowing me to interact with certain elements on webpages. Here is a list of some of the websites that I have trouble with:

- railsapis.codeschool.com/levels/1/challenges/1 and railscasts.com/episodes/417-foundation?autoplay=true

  I can't use the video controls
- soundcloud.com/jo-o-anderson-1/loreen-euphoria

  I can't use the seekbar.
- yashry.com/search?q=iPhone

  The arrows of the price range slider don't drag. Instead, the underlying text is selected.

I tried using Firefox on a friend's Mac and it's working properly. I guess it's a problem with an entry in my about:config, but I don't even know what to search for to describe this problem.

I'm using Firefox 33.1.1 on Mac OS X 10.10.1 (14B25).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `dom.w3c_touch_events.enabled` to `0` in **about:config** solved it.